# Why URL re-writing is not working when I do not use slash at the end?

Tags: kubernetes, url, url-rewriting, kubernetes-ingress

I have a simple ingress configuration file-

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /link2/link3/
  name: tut-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - host: tutorial.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /link1/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx-ingress-tut-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

in which requests coming to `/link1` or `/link1/` are rewritten to
`/link2/link3/`.
When I access it using `http://tutorial.com/link1/`
I am shown the correct result but when I access it using
`http://tutorial.com/link1`, I get a 404 not found.

The `nginx-ingress-tut-service` has the following endpoints-

- `/`
- `/link1`
- `/link2/link3`

I am a beginner in the web domain, any help will be appreciated.

When I change it to-

```yaml
- path: /link1
```

it starts working fine, but can anybody tell why is it not working with `/link1/`.

Helpful resources -
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

Edit- Please also explain what happens when you write a full HTTP link in
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`

Comment: I can share the deployment and service file as well, the image is also deployed on the docker hub, I am willing to provide every detail.

Comment: Well, `/link1/` is not a prefix of `/link1` because a prefix must match the beginning of the target string. The target string `/link1` is simply missing the ending `/` that the prefix `/link1/` has.

Comment: @Lukman But in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples if you scroll down a bit, you will see the documentation mentions `Prefix  /foo/  /foo, /foo/  Yes` Where Yes is for matches

Comment: @Lukman If you scroll down a bit further you will see
`Prefix  /aaa/bbb/  /aaa/bbb  Yes, ignores trailing slash`, the documentation explicitly mentions about ignoring trailing slash.

Comment: @Lukman Do you have some time? it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is posted in the comment:

> Well, `/link1/` is not a prefix of `/link1` because a prefix must be the same length or longer than the target string

If you have

```yaml
- path: /link1/
```

the string to match will have to have a `/` character at the end of the path. Everything works correctly. In this situation if you try to access by the link `http://tutorial.com/link1` you will get 404 error, because ingress was expecting  `http://tutorial.com/link1/`.

For more you can see [examples of rewrite rule](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#examples) and documentation about [path types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types):

> Each path in an Ingress is required to have a corresponding path type. Paths that do not include an explicit  `pathType`  will fail validation. There are three supported path types:
>
> - `ImplementationSpecific`: With this path type, matching is up to the IngressClass. Implementations can treat this as a separate  `pathType`  or treat it identically to  `Prefix`  or  `Exact`  path types.
> - `Exact`: Matches the URL path exactly and with case sensitivity.
> - **`Prefix`: Matches based on a URL path prefix split by  `/`. Matching is case sensitive and done on a path element by element basis. A path element refers to the list of labels in the path split by the  `/`  separator. A request is a match for path  *p*  if every  *p*  is an element-wise prefix of  *p*  of the request path.**

**EDIT:**
Based on documentation this should work, but it looks like there is a [fresh problem with nginx ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/8047). The problem is still unresolved. You can use workaround posted in [this topic](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/646) or try to change your you similar to this:

```
- path: /link1(/|$)
```

Comment: But in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples if you scroll down a bit, you will see the documentation mentions 

`Prefix  /foo/  /foo, /foo/  Yes`
Where Yes is for matches

Comment: If you scroll even down further you will see
`Prefix  /aaa/bbb/  /aaa/bbb  Yes, ignores trailing slash`

Comment: Can you please explain how is this happening?

Comment: Do you have some time? it will be really appreciated.

Comment: The problem looks like connected directly to nginx ingress and it is described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/8047). For more look at my edited answer.

Comment: You are a legend for helping me with this, I really appreciate it, thanks a lot man.